# How to resolve import cufflinks error "The plotly.plotly module is deprecated"?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, cufflinks

On importing cufflinks I am getting error in Jupyter Notebook:

> ```
> import cufflinks as cf
>
> error:
> The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
> please install the chart-studio package and use the
> chart_studio.plotly module instead.
> ```

What to do? Is there any other way I can plot my data frames using plotly?

Comment: Which version of plotly are you using?

Comment: Please be more specific when asking questions.